# How to make post request in WebView in Android with content type multipart/form-data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, multipartform-data

I need to load url inside Android WebView and I need to pass there also body params using multipart/form-data. And I have no ideas, how this can be done inside Android WebView.
Could you please help me. Maybe we can use MultipartBody.Builder(), but how?
Thanks